# Hydration in Ardent

Tags: orm, laravel, ardent

Could you clarify what is the difference between

```
autoHydrateEntityFromInput
```

and

```
forceEntityHydrationFromInput
```

? I cannot get it. If I set first property to true then I'll always get input data hydrated to model, but then what's the second property?

Answer (score 0):

From the Ardent source code comments:

> By default, Ardent will attempt hydration only if the model object
>   contains no attributes and the $autoHydrateEntityFromInput property is
>   set to true.
>
> Setting $forceEntityHydrationFromInput to true will bypass the above
>   check and enforce hydration of model attributes.

For example, if you do:

```
Model::create(["title"->"My Title"]);
```

then autoHydrateEntityFromInput will not hydrate but forceEntityHydrationFromInput will.